# If else Conditions in odoo qweb

Tags: xml, odoo, qwebview, qweb

I have many2many field called ( language )

```
class customer_analysis(models.Model):
   _name = 'customer_analysis.anaylsis'

   name = fields.Char(readonly=True, default=lambda self: _('New'))
   language = fields.Many2many('language.analysis', string="Language")

class language_analysis(models.Model):  
   _name = 'language.analysis'
   name = fields.Char(string="Language")
```

And from odoo qweb report, I have iterated through (language) field and inside it,I need to check if this field contains (English) value or not. So what I did is, t-if the field does not contain (English) value do something and t-else do something.

```
              <div>
               <td colspan="3">
                 <t t-foreach="doc.language" t-as="do">
                    <t t-if="not do.name in 'English'">
                      <input type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom:5px;"/>&#160;English
                    </t>
                   <t t-else="">
                      <input type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom:5px;" checked="True"/>&#160;English
                   </t>
                 </t>
                </td>
             </div>
```

But the block of code below is not working, so what is the right expression or comparison needed to make this block running if the field does not contain (English) value.

```
     <t t-if="not do.name in 'English'">
                  <input type="checkbox" style="margin-bottom:5px;"/>&#160;English
                </t>
```

I have tried different way that does not work too like

```
  1. <t t-if ="do.name != 'English'"> 
  2. <t t-if="'English' not in do.name">
```

Comment: Does here type of 'do.name' is string ?

Comment: yes, It is a string

Comment: did you find the answer yet?